# Children Markdown Remark

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a query and I am using "markdown remark" to change markdown to HTML.

My query currently looks like:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allContentfulQuestionAnswer {
        edges {
          node {
            question
            answer {
              childrenMarkdownRemark {
                html
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

However, I am mapping through the question and answers.. and nothing shows up..
The weird thing is, when I use "childMarkdownRemark".. instead of "childrenMarkdownRemark" the answers show.. but only the first table turns into HTML.

Does anyone know why nothing would show up with childrenMarkdownRemark?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how are you rendering the content?

Comment: @FerranBuireu this is how I am rendering the content:

`return (
<>
<h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>
{data.allContentfulQuestionAnswer.edges.map(( {node, index} ) => {
return(
<div key={node.question} className="repairCost">
<p>{node.question}</p>
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML=
{{ __html: node.answer.childrenMarkdownRemark.html}} />
</div>
)})}
</>
`